# How to set value of property of Class B using Plugin (Class A)

Tags: magento2, email-templates, invoice, plugin

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::InvoiceIncrementId" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\InvoiceSaveBefore" />
</type>
```

**Plugin code:**

```
public function aroundGetIncrementId(
   \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice,
   \Closure $closure
)
{
   ..
   $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate);
   ..
}
```

The template ID is set in the plugin. But, it is not found in SenderBuilder.php class. Instead, `$this->templateContainer->getTemplateId()` in `\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder.php` returns default template.

If I set the `TemplateId` in **plugin**, how can I get it in Email\SenderBuilder.php class to send an email with Custom Template?

Comment: What you requirement, Want to use custom template id when invoice   email send

Comment: Multiple Invoice with multiple templates. Based on Invoice_type, its template will be set and send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea of using Plugin in this way is not correct. Because, a plugin modifies the behavior of functions of that type [class] ideally. If that class instantiates another class, you can modify that instantiated object too.

Should I delete this question or helpful if anyone do the same wrong design?